# How to perform rolling window calculations without SSC packages

Tags: stata

**Goal:** perform rolling window calculations on panel data in Stata with variables `PanelVar`, `TimeVar`, and `Var1`, where the window can change within a loop over different window sizes.

**Problem:** no access to SSC for the packages that would take care of this (like `rangestat`)

I know that

```
by PanelVar: gen Var1_1 = Var1[_n]
```

produces a copy of `Var1` in `Var1_1`. So I thought it would make sense to try

```
by PanelVar: gen Var1SumLag = sum(Var1[(_n-3)/_n])
```

to produce a rolling window calculation for `_n-3` to `_n` for the whole variable. But it fails to produce the results I want, it just produces zeros.

You could use `sum(Var1) - sum(Var1[_n-3])`, but I also want to be able to make the rolling window left justified (summing future observations) as well as right justified (summing past observations).

Essentially I would like to replicate Python's "`.rolling().agg()`" functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Stata `_n` is the index of the current observation. The expression `(_n - 3) / _n` yields -2 when `_n` is 1 and increases slowly with `_n` but  is always less than 1. As a subscript applied to extract values from observations of a variable it always yields missing values given an extra rule that Stata rounds down expressions so supplied. Hence it reduces to -2, -1 or 0: in each case it yields missing values when given as a subscript. Experiment will show you that given any numeric variable say `numvar` references to `numvar[-2]` or `numvar[-1]` or `numvar[0]` all yield missing values. Otherwise put, you seem to be hoping that the `/` yields a set of subscripts that return a sequence you can sum over, but that is a long way from what Stata will do in that context: the `/` is just interpreted as division.  (The running sum of missings is always returned as 0, which is an expression of missings being ignored in that calculation: just as 2 + 3 + . + 4 is returned as 9 so also . + . + . + . is returned as 0.)

A fairly general way to do what you want is to use time series operators, and this is strongly preferable to subscripts as (1) doing the right thing with gaps (2) automatically working for panels too. Thus after a `tsset` or `xtset`

```
L0.numvar + L1.numvar + L2.numvar + L3.numvar
```

yields the sum of the current value and the three previous and

```
L0.numvar + F1.numvar + F2.numvar + F3.numvar
```

yields the sum of the current value and the three next. If any of these terms is missing, the sum will be too; a work-around for that is to return say

```
cond(missing(L3.numvar), 0, L3.numvar)
```

More general code will require some kind of loop.

Given a desire to loop over lags (negative) and leads (positive) some code might look like this, given a range of subscripts as local macros `i` <= `j`

```
 * example i and j 
 local i = -3
 local j = 0 

 gen double wanted = 0 
 forval k = `i'/`j' { 
     if `k' < 0 { 
         local k1 = -(`k') 
         replace wanted = wanted + L`k1'.numvar
     } 
     else replace wanted = wanted + F`k'.numvar 
}
```

Alternatively, use Mata.

EDIT There's a simpler method, to use `tssmooth ma` to get moving averages and then multiply up by the number of terms.

```
  tssmooth ma wanted1=numvar, w(3 1) 
  tssmooth ma wanted2=numvar, w(0 1 3) 
  replace wanted1 = 4 * wanted1 
  replace wanted2 = 4 * wanted2
```

Note that in contrast to the method above `tssmooth ma` uses whatever is available at the beginning and end of each panel. So, the first moving average, the average of the first value and the three previous, is returned as just the first value at the beginning of each panel (when the three previous values are unknown).

Comment: I wanted to use time series operators originally, but I had no idea how to make them dynamic in a loop, the L`k' notation does exactly what I need it to. Coming from Python and just starting to learn STATA.

Comment: Fine, but please note -- as in my silent edit -- that the standard spelling is Stata. More at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1443889-why-stata-not-stata-or-others and https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling

Comment: Duly noted, I hadn't given it much thought.

Comment: How would you take the maximum of a rolling window using these time series operators? I haven't figured that one out yet.

Comment: `max(numvar, L1.numvar, L2.numvar)` illustrates technique.

Comment: Thanks for this, how could you have an automatically expanding or shrinking list of lags and leads within the `max` function? For example on one pass of the loop it could be `max(numvar, L1.numvar)` while on the next it would be `max(numvar, L1.numvar, L2.numvar)`.

Comment: Indeed, but please ask a new question.